# ADODB What is the meaning of parameters in CreateParameter

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I don't know any ASP, Sql server or ADODB. And this is the first time i am trying to do something with them. I want to add new entries to the database. Current code is like that:

```
set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
Cmd.CommandText = "Make_something"
Cmd.prepared = true
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@Name", 200, 1, 50, Name)
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("@Birthday", 135, 1, 10, Birthday)
```

I want to add a new entry for example like "City". But i don't know the second, third and fourth parameters(for Name 200, 1 and 50) do.

Comment: Googling is a programmer's most important skill.

Comment: This is where google got me, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...CreateParameter(NAME,TYPE,DIRECTION,SIZE,VALUE)

NAME: name of the parameter

TYPE: must be a data type. 200, for example, is a varchar.

DIRECTION: Input, Output, Retrurn Value,... 1 is Input.

SIZE: Size of type. In your first example, 50 characters

VALUE: The data.

You can use more friendly values if include adovbs.inc 
If so, for your first example:

```
  CreateParameter("@Name", AdVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Name)
```

You can get the constants here:
[Adovbs.inc](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005432/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/Beginner/faq7.shtml)

Comment: Don't use the `adovbs.inc` or `adovbs.asp`, instead [use METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml). Consider specifying `METADATA` in the `global.asa` so DLL constants are available to the entire application, rather then specifying `adovbs` on a page by page basis.

Comment: The OP doesn't know Classic ASP, ADODB or SQL Server providing an answer here is pointless. Plus the answer doesn't answer the OPs question anyway.

Comment: The OP says: "But i don't know the second, third and fourth parameters". Now, thanks to the answer, he knows it.

Comment: Yes but the OP also says *(right at the beginning of the question)* *"I don't know any ASP, Sql server or ADODB"*, so now thanks to you they know what?, how to set a parameter to a language / syntax they are have never used? Bravo.

Comment: Gradually he will know more. Not judge if it is right way to learn or face a job.

Comment: Exactly *"gradually"*, in other words this isn't the right place for that. What the OP needs is a tutorial which is not what SO provide. By answering the question you are providing a false impression of what SO is all about. Tab said it best in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053173/adodb-what-is-the-meaning-of-parameters-in-createparameter/30054770?noredirect=1#comment48223776_30053173) - *"Googling is a programmer's most important skill"*.